# dateFromString does not work correctly in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, nsstring, ios6, nsdate

This code worked in iOS 5, but it returns a wrong year in iOS 6. Any idea why?

```
NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSLocale *locale=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar: gregorian];
    [dateFormatter setLocale: locale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

    NSDate* date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"9000"]];

    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

    [gregorian release];
    [locale release];
    [dateFormatter release];
```

The above produces date 9000 in iOS 5, and date 2000 in iOS 6!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see if you log `date`?

Comment: Changing 9000 to 2012 gives consistently same results on both iOS 5 and 6. Both the stringFromDate as well as the raw NSDate are consistent across iOS 5 and 6 for years like 2012. Maybe something's odd with 9000!

Comment: it works for 3512 but not for 3513 ie it can go furthur for 1500 years i guess

Comment: Non-distant dates work correctly on both iOS 5 and 6. Distant dates work only on iOS 5. It appears that in iOS 6, the NSGregorianCalendar does not work with distant dates. It appears that the NSISO8601Calendar is required instead. Is this something that I can change safely?

Comment: I checked and found that the behavior is same for all years after 3512 return the dates in 19th and 20th century and not beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by replacing NSGregorianCalendar with NSISO8601Calendar:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSISO8601Calendar];
```

This works, but I would feel better if I know why. Does anybody know the difference between NSGregorianCalendar and NSISO8601Calendar?

Answer (score -1):

Its look like Apple add "own Maya calendar" in IOS 6
I can't find anithing about it in docs, but i try for myself and its look like after 3512 year automaticly sets lover year like 2013 (is year 3513), 2014 (if y 3514) etc..

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:gregorian];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"3512"];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```